# How to change TextBlock font size using a VisualState?

Tags: xaml, windows-10, win-universal-app

I have a page that doesn't want to set the font size of a TextBlock as it resizes. I am using a VisualStateManager, but I must be doing something wrong.

```
    <Page
        x:Class="MyUWP.Pages.SplashPage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="using:StoryFractalUWP.Pages"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualState x:Name="Narrow">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="MainTitle.FontSize" Value="36" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="600" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="MainTitle.FontSize" Value="72" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Wide">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1000" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="MainTitle.FontSize" Value="110" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <RelativePanel Background="White" x:Name="MainPanel">
            <TextBlock x:Name="MainTitle" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
                       RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True"
                       >MyApp</TextBlock>

        </RelativePanel>
    </Page>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should work if you put *VisualStateManager* code inside *RelativePanel*:

```
<RelativePanel Background="White" x:Name="MainPanel">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="Narrow">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MainTitle.FontSize" Value="36" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="600" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MainTitle.FontSize" Value="72" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Wide">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1000" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MainTitle.FontSize" Value="110" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <TextBlock x:Name="MainTitle" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
                   RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True" FontSize="20" Foreground="Red"
                   >MyApp</TextBlock>
</RelativePanel>
```

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly my problem.

Comment: As a little comment, is not about using a RelativePanel, but putting the VisualStates in the first container of your page, it could be a grid, stack panel, relative panel or anything else... just my two cents